Can Windows 11 access first-gen IDE drives, set-up using CHS under MS-DOS 3.3, and connected using an IDE to USB bridge device?
I've several first generation IDE drives (from MiniScribe & Conner Peripherals) partitioned and formatted under MS-DOS 3.3. Can the files on their primary and extended FAT16 partitions be copied from them using Windows 11, a modern UEFI BIOS notebook, and an IDE to USB bridge?
I've not had much luck so far... Which got me wondering about CHS geometries and BIOS drive table definitions. The drives were set-up on 80386DX systems, using their native (untranslated) physical CHS parameters, entered into user-defined BIOS drive table entries.
I presume they must now be addressed in terms of LBA under Windows 11--as there is nowhere on the USB bridge, or in the UEFI BIOS, to enter CHS parameters?
If a bench with vintage hardware is needed, I can do it. Though it'd be fun to access these influential early units via USB and Windows 11.

Try winding up a VM with a more capable OS and pass these devices through into it.

Before worrying about "CHS geometries and BIOS drive table definitions" you have to consider the likely incompatibility of a "first generation IDE drive" and the USB-to-IDE adapter (which probably supports ATA-3). Also experiment with the drive addressing, i.e. the Master/Slave/CS jumpers.  Beware that old HDDs had rather large power/current draws on startup. IOW don't use a wimpy power supply.

Most of these USB-IDE adapters expect the drive to be jumpered as slave (no mention of that in the manual), while some require them to be master. And CS almost NEVER works with very old drives, no matter what the manual of the IDE-USB adapter says.
And you may need a beefier powersupply for the drive as @sawdust already mentioned.


I presume they must now be addressed in terms of LBA under Windows 11--as there is nowhere on the USB bridge, or in the UEFI BIOS, to enter CHS parameters?

Your concerns may be misdirected. Rather than worry about "CHS geometries and BIOS drive table definitions", you have to consider the likely incompatibility of a "first generation IDE drive" and the USB-to-IDE adapter, which probably only supports the later (and more common) ATA-2 and Enhanced IDE drives.
According to the Wikipedia article on Parallel ATA, logical block addressing (LBA) was introduced with the IDE (pre-ATA) interface. But the IDE interface wasn't standardized until ANSI released the first draft of the AT Attachment specification. So a USB-to-IDE adapter (which would be implemented in silicon) is most likely to support only an ANSI-standardized version of the IDE interface (to ensure product reliability).

As an experiment I tested with a USB-to-PATA/SATA adapter that is over a decade old on a Linux system. When plugged in this USB adapter produces the following syslog messages:
 usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
 usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=2338
 usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
 usb 1-7: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
 usb 1-7: Manufacturer: JMicron
 usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 222222222222

These procedures were performed on a Linux system because of the more-informative system messages to understand what might be happening.

An old Maxtor 72004AP drive that has an ATA-2, Enhanced IDE interface can be read using the USB-IDE adapter:
[  202.366924] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  202.367903] scsi host7: usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[  203.370807] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Maxtor 7 M83S             0B31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[  203.371444] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[  203.375296] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] 3924360 512-byte logical blocks: (2.01 GB/1.87 GiB)
[  203.376651] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[  203.376657] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
[  203.380622] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Asking for cache data failed
[  203.380630] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  203.453294]  sdf: sdf1 sdf2 < sdf5 sdf6 > sdf3
                sdf3: <solaris: [s0] sdf7 [s1] sdf8 [s2] sdf9 [s8] sdf10 [s9] sdf11 >
[  203.458670] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
[  208.969647] ufs: ufs was compiled with read-only support, can't be mounted as read-write
[  208.970463] ufs: You didn't specify the type of your ufs filesystem
               
               mount -t ufs -o ufstype=sun|sunx86|44bsd|ufs2|5xbsd|old|hp|nextstep|nextstep-cd|openstep ...
               
               >>>WARNING<<< Wrong ufstype may corrupt your filesystem, default is ufstype=old
[  392.030361] NILFS version 2 loaded

Note that this drive was jumpered for Master selection.

A Conner Peripherals CP-344 drive that has an original IDE interface could be identified using the USB-IDE adapter but cannot be read :
[ 1863.463383] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1863.466909] scsi host8: usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[ 1864.465896] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Conner P JE                    PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[ 1864.466881] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[ 1864.473505] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 1864.475103] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Using 0xffffffff as device size
[ 1864.475120] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] 4294967296 512-byte logical blocks: (2.20 TB/2.00 TiB)
[ 1864.480340] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Write Protect is off
[ 1864.480356] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Mode Sense: 00 38 00 00
[ 1864.485407] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Asking for cache data failed
[ 1864.485425] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 1864.486485] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[ 1864.491134] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Using 0xffffffff as device size
[ 1864.495557] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 1864.495572] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Sense Key : Illegal Request [current] 
[ 1864.495582] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
[ 1864.495592] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00 00
[ 1864.495600] blk_update_request: critical target error, dev sdf, sector 0
[ 1864.495609] Buffer I/O error on dev sdf, logical block 0, async page read


Note the Illegal Request and Invalid command operation code error messages while probing this drive. This would seem to indicate that this original IDE drive is not properly responding to ATA or SCSI requests.
